# keep unique words in a pandas dataframe row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, set, pattern-matching, unique

Dataframe:

```
> df
>type(df)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

ID      Property Type                                Amenities
1952043 Apartment, Villa, Apartment                  Park, Jogging Track, Park
1918916 Bungalow, Cottage House, Cottage, Bungalow   Garden, Play Ground
```

How can I keep just the unique **words** separated by "comma" in the dataframe row? In this case it **must not** consider "Cottage House" and "Cottage" same. It must check this for **all columns** of the dataframe. So my desired output should look like below:
Desired Output :

```
    ID      Property Type                      Amenities
    1952043 Apartment, Villa                   Park, Jogging Track
    1918916 Bungalow, Cottage House, Cottage   Garden, Play Ground
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I create a function that does what you want for a given string. Secondly, I apply this function to all strings in the column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Apartment, Villa, Apartment',
                    'Park, Jogging Track, Park'],
                   ['Bungalow, Cottage House, Cottage, Bungalow',
                    'Garden, Play Ground']],
                  columns=['Property Type', 'Amenities'])

def drop_duplicates(row):
    # Split string by ', ', drop duplicates and join back.
    words = row.split(', ')
    return ', '.join(np.unique(words).tolist())

# drop_duplicates is applied to all rows of df.
df['Property Type'] = df['Property Type'].apply(drop_duplicates)
df['Amenities'] = df['Amenities'].apply(drop_duplicates)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I want this code to remove duplicates from all the columns of the dataframe. I have modified my question, can you check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into pandas DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep='\t')
>>> df['Property Type'].apply(lambda cell: set([c.strip() for c in cell.split(',')]))
0                    {Apartment, Villa}
1    {Cottage, Bungalow, Cottage House}
Name: Property Type, dtype: object
```

The main idea is to

1. iterate through every row,
2. split the string in the target column by `,`
3. return the unique `set()` of the list from step 2

**Code:**

```
>>> for row in proptype_column: # Step 1.
...     items_in_row = row.split(', ') # Step 2. 
...     uniq_items_in_row = set(row.split(', ')) # Step 3. 
...     print(uniq_items_in_row)
... 
set(['Apartment', 'Villa'])
set(['Cottage', 'Bungalow', 'Cottage House'])
```

Now you can achieve the same with `DataFrame.apply()` function:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep='\t')
>>> df['Property Type'].apply(lambda cell: set([c.strip() for c in cell.split(',')]))
0                    {Apartment, Villa}
1    {Cottage, Bungalow, Cottage House}
Name: Property Type, dtype: object
>>> proptype_uniq = df['Property Type'].apply(lambda cell: set(cell.split(', ')))
>>> df['Property Type (Unique)'] = proptype_uniq
>>> df
      ID                               Property Type  \
0  12345                 Apartment, Villa, Apartment   
1  67890  Bungalow, Cottage House, Cottage, Bungalow   

                   Amenities              Property Type (Unique)  
0  Park, Jogging Track, Park                  {Apartment, Villa}  
1        Garden, Play Ground  {Cottage, Bungalow, Cottage House}
```